# How to hang things on wall where 1/2" drywall covers solid material (steel?)

Tags: drywall, walls, drywall-anchor

I own a condo in a high rise building (*mid-1970s construction*).
The walls are 1/2" drywall, and I'm guessing the structure is steel (*perhaps with concrete?*).

The other day I was attempting to add some wall hooks (*rather beefy, made of solid brass*) to a wall in my entryway, but I could not get a drywall anchor to go deeper than 1/2" before hitting something impenetrable. I've been able to use drywall anchors on other walls in my apartment, so it appears that this wall may just be load bearing or perhaps have wires or pipe running through it. Because of that possibility, I don't particularly want to try using a masonry bit to drill farther to see if it is in fact concrete

So, I'm wondering if it's possible to hang these hooks somehow. Are there drywall anchors that are only 1/2" long? Other options?

Comment: Did you try multiple locations in that wall, or just one?

Comment: Multiple locations. The wall is about 17" wide and I tried 5 locations horizontally across it. Hard for me to tell exactly how wide the metal stud(s) may be but it certainly seems to be most of it.

Comment: Hmmm...that sounds like a column, not a wall.

Comment: Could be. If it is, is there a way to anchor into it?

Comment: how much do the things to be hung weigh? A down-angled nail/brad should still be good for at least 15lbs, repeat as needed. Command hooks can do several pounds as well. If it is steel directly behind, supermagnets might work; i've hung speakers with those...

Comment: Structural columns often run from the bottom to the top of multi-story buildings are 1) often stacked and become a chase for plumbing and electrical. These spaces are protected so there is no damage to the utilities AND is often smelly so you wouldn’t want to drill into it and let the smells escape into your home anyway. Or 2) there are strict fire codes that require layers of non-combustible construction made up of steel and plaster. I’d leave it alone.